# Probability-generating function and variance

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}_{0}$, with probability-generating function $G(z) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} p(x) z^x$. Assume that $p(0) > 0$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X]$ is finite. Why do these conditions imply that the integral $\int_{0}^{1} (1-z)(G(z)-z)^{-1} dz$ diverges to $+ \infty$? I do not see the intuition behind this integral, or its relation to the expectation and variance of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G^\prime(1^-)=\mu=1$ and $G^{\prime\prime}(1^-)=\mu^2+\sigma^2-\mu=\sigma^2$,$$G(1-\epsilon)=G(1^-)-G^\prime(1^-)\epsilon+\frac12G^{\prime\prime}(1^-)\epsilon^2+o(\epsilon^2)=1-\epsilon+\frac12\sigma^2\epsilon^2+o(\epsilon^2)$$for $0<\epsilon\ll1$, i.e. $G(z)-z=\frac12\sigma^2(1-z)^2+o((1-z)^2)$ for $z$ slightly less than $1$. So at the upper limit, the integral diverges like $\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\int_c^1\frac{dz}{1-z}$. (By contrast, at the lower limit the integrand approximates $1$.)

Comment: Intuitively, I understand your proof, since the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dz}{1-z}$ does not converge. But strictly speaking, we have shown that
$$ \tag{1}
\frac{1-z}{G(z) - z} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} (1-z) + o(1-z)}
$$
for $z \uparrow 1$.

Comment: But now I would like to get rid of the Landau symbol and show that the integral of the LHS diverges. In other words, I would like to justify an inequality of the form
$$ \tag{2}
\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1-z}{G(z) - z}dz \geq c \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{1-z}dz = + \infty
$$
for some $\varepsilon >0$ small enough and some constant $c > 0$. I am not sure if the equation (1) implies (2).

Comment: @user63841219 Cool name for $o$! So what we want is for the $\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\sigma^2}o(1-z)}$ factor to have a positive lower bound $c$ on $(1-\epsilon,\,1)$, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. If it didn't, the $o(1-z)$ would be unbounded above on that interval, regardless of how small $\epsilon>0$ is; but then it wouldn't be able to approach $0$ faster than $1-z$ does.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your argument. Why do you consider the fraction $\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\sigma^2}o(1-z)}$ and what is $s$? I think we need to bound exactly the expression of my equation $(1)$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, $s$ is a typo for $2$. The point here is to multiple a positive integrand by a function $\ge c>0$, thereby multiplying the integral equal to $\infty$ by $\ge c$.

Comment: Thank you, let me try to show it slowly: We want to show that $\exists \epsilon > 0$ $\forall z \in [1-\epsilon,1]$ $\exists c > 0$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} (1-z) + o(1-z)} \leq 
\frac{c}{ 1-z}.
$$

Comment: By contradiction, let us assume that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists z \in [1-\epsilon,1]$ $\forall c > 0$
$$
\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} (1-z) + o(1-z) \leq
\frac{1-z}{c}.
$$

Comment: This is equivalent to $o(1) \leq 1/c - \sigma^2/2$. Thus, $o(1) \leq - C^{2}$, for $c > 0$ large enough. This means, that as $z \uparrow 1$, $o(1)$ cannot converge to zero, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @user63841219 Pretty much. Most sources don't make it that explicit!

Comment: I hope "pretty much" means "completely" in this case. Many thanks for your help, the proof is now clear to me.

Comment: But I am still a little bit puzzled by this result, i.e., the fact that finite variance implies the divergence of this integral. I am trying to think of a couterexample, i.e., that the integral diverges, but the other properties are still satisfied (except for the finite variance assumption). You may want to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468906/probability-distribution-on-mathbbn-0-such-that-1-zgz-z-1-is. So far, everything I wrote down turned out to have a finite variance.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_x xp(x) = G'(1)$ and the condition that the variance is finite amounts to a finite second moment, in other words $G''(1) = \sum_x x^2 p(x) < \infty$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know these identities. In fact, I think we should write left-sided limits, because power series only converge in general inside their convergence radius. My problem is I do not see how to manipulate the integral in order to see the connection with the derivatives of $G$.

Comment: I think your expression for $G''(1)$ is wrong. You also have to subtract $1$, the expectation.

Comment: @user63841219 You are right, if $G(x) = \sum p(x) z^x$ then $G''(x) = \sum p(x) x (x-1) z^{x-2}...$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Taylor series of $G(z)-z$ around $(z-1)$. You'll get that the term in $(z-1)^1$ vanishes, but the term in $(z-1)^2$ does not. This causes the integral to blow up around $z=1$, just like the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ from $0$ to $1$ diverges.